# I can't install pop_os! on a partition of a disk with windows installed

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, grub, pop-os

I have been trying to install pop_os! for weeks... At this point I feel so stupid... trying different solutions like changing partition sizes, disabling safe boot mode or windows fast boot, trying to find similar errors on google... Nothing has worked, the pop_os! installation always throws the following error message after 1-2 minutes:

[image]

I have finally collected the logs of my pop_os installation and made screenshots of how the disks are partitioned:

[image]

> Here above I cannot understand why pop forces me to format into a ext4
> partition... In gparted is formatted as FAT32!!! And so it should be
> /boot/efi right??... Tried to select "custom" in "Use as" section and type /boot/efi
> manually, but it seems not to work.

[image]

> Notice the warning icon, Is it unable to read because it is an EFI partition? Windows Bootloader on sda2 has the same warning . It is bad to have 2 EFI partitions?? Also, I know 2GB is a lot for EFI partition but... just desperate trying to do something different and I've watched some tutorials where that size is used specially on pop os!...

Here my lsblk:

```
NAME         SIZE FSTYPE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0        2.5G squashfs /rofs
sda        223.6G          
├─sda1       499M ntfs     
├─sda2       100M vfat     
├─sda3     114.2G ntfs     
├─sda4         2G ext4     
├─sda5      95.7G ext4     
└─sda6        11G swap     
sdb         14.5G          //Live USB using Ventoy
├─sdb1      14.4G exfat    
│ └─ventoy   2.8G          /media/pop-os/Pop_OS 22.04 amd64 Intel
└─sdb2        32M iso9660  /media/pop-os/Pop_OS 22.04 amd64 Intel
sdc            0B
```

An here the last part of the logs where the installation always fails (complete log file is on a google drive link at the end). It seems to fail on grub installation step, and why is trying to install in BIOS mode? my PC has UEFI.

```bash
[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:103] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.vZLr2nxp1R5g" "kernelstub" "--esp-path" "/boot/efi" "--add-options" "quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false splash" "--loader" "--manage-only" "--force-update" "--verbose"
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] chroot: fallo al ejecutar la orden «kernelstub»: No existe el archivo o el directorio
[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:103] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.vZLr2nxp1R5g" "update-grub"
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] Generating grub configuration file ...
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-76051900-generic
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-76051900-generic
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] done
[INFO distinst:src/installer/steps/configure/chroot_conf.rs:289] configuring keyboard layout
[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:103] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.vZLr2nxp1R5g" "localectl" "set-x11-keymap" "es" "" ""
[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:103] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.vZLr2nxp1R5g" "/usr/bin/env" "-i" "SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT=_" "openvt" "--" "sh" "/etc/init.d/console-setup.sh" "reload"
[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:103] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.vZLr2nxp1R5g" "ln" "-s" "/etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz" "/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz"
[INFO distinst:src/installer/steps/configure/chroot_conf.rs:277] re-enabling update-initramfs
[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:103] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.vZLr2nxp1R5g" "sh" "-c" "rm /usr/sbin/update-initramfs"
[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:103] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.vZLr2nxp1R5g" "sh" "-c" "mv /usr/sbin/update-initramfs.bak /usr/sbin/update-initramfs"
[INFO distinst:src/installer/state.rs:33] starting configuring bootloader step
[INFO distinst:src/installer/steps/bootloader.rs:35] /dev/sda: installing bootloader for Bios
[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:103] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.vZLr2nxp1R5g" "grub-install" "--recheck" "--target=i386-pc" "/dev/sda"
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] Instalando para plataforma i386-pc.
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] grub-install: aviso: esta etiqueta de partición GPT no contiene ninguna Partición de 
Arranque BIOS; el embebido no será posible.
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] grub-install: aviso: El embebido no es posible.  GRUB podrá ser instalado con esta
 configuración únicamente usando listas de bloques.  No obstante, las listas de bloques son INSEGURAS y su uso está desaconsejado..
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] grub-install: error: no se procederá con las listas de bloques.
[ERROR distinst:src/installer/state.rs:37] configuring bootloader error: command failed with exit status: exit status: 1
[ERROR distinst:src/installer/mod.rs:300] errored while installing system: command failed with exit status: exit status: 1
[INFO distinst:ffi/src/installer.rs:190] Install error: command failed with exit status: exit status: 1
```

Complete logs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/162WdYhL4S9CNMZDtvBt8MmM4jstlNpeK/view?usp=sharing

Sorry for the question size but I tried to provide all the data I have and now at this point it is a personal matter between me and pop os. Thank you for your attention.

Hardware:

- Motherboard Ticnova e70 SFF (has ASRock UEFI)
- Ryzen 5 2600
- 16 GB RAM
- KINGSTON 240 GB SSD
- Nvidia GF 710 Series

Answer (score 0):

This is the hint in your logfile:

```
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] Instalando para plataforma i386-pc.
[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:93] grub-install: aviso: esta etiqueta de partición GPT no contiene ninguna Partición de 
Arranque BIOS; el embebido no será posible.
```

Translated:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label does not contain any GPT partitions.
BIOS boot; embedding will not be possible.
```

It means you were booting the installer in BIOS mode and trying to partition the disk for UEFI.
The installer tried to install GRUB i386-pc and failed.

Change the boot order in your BIOS and disable legacy boot if necessary. On some motherboards the boot option to `/efi/boot/grubx64.efi` needs to be added manually if it is not detected. See [iso boot problem with UEFI on 20.04](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/951).

Since you already have an existing ESP (`/dev/sda2`), you should reuse it. Creating more than one ESP is not recommended.

You were also trying to create a FAT `/boot` partition which is not the same as the EFI System Partition. The ESP is only mounted inside `/boot` as `/boot/efi`.